# How to add Bcc while sending Bulk emails in Sendgrid?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid API to send bulk emails, it is working just perfect. Now client wants to Bcc his email whenever a request is made to Sendgrid to send bulk emails.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    $sendgrid = new SendGrid($user_sendgrid, $pass_sendgrid);
    $email = new SendGrid\Email();
    $email
        ->setSmtpapiTos($emails)
        ->setFrom(<Sender Email>)
        ->setSubject(' ')
        ->setText(' ')
        ->addBcc(<Bcc Email>)
        ->addSubstitution("[firstname]", $firstname)
        ->addSubstitution("[lastname]", $lastname)
        ->setHtml(' ');
    $sendgrid->send($email);
```

It send emails to users, but not to the one who is Bcc'd.

Comment: We have faced the issue before, SendGrid API servers removes the duplicate `to` receipients while sending bulk emails, may be the same happening to you, you should mail to SendGrid support team about your concern..

Comment: you can also have a look at **sendgrid webapi 3.0**, docs here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php, also try this example code with JSON request which has BCC option in it.. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/mail/mail.php

Comment: @NishantSolanki i have checked it, the second one is not the Bulk email, it is possible to add Cc and Bcc in simple mail script of sendgrid, but i couldn't find it for Bulk email.

Comment: the example link I provided the `to` object seems like an array, have you tried using the same script adding multiple elements into `to` ??

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the SMTPAPI To addresses, the Native To/BCC/CC addresses get dropped. You instead need to set the [BCC Filter value](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/apps.html#bcc) within the SMTPAPI string.

Be aware that this BCC address uses a Credit on SendGrid as well, since you're effectively doubling your mail volume.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bcc the sender itself, its possible. Tho my solution is add also the user on the bcc. I use here Sendgrid API ver 3 + Laravel:

```
    $email = "sender@mail.com";
    $subject = "Email Subject";
    $body = "Body of email";

    $bccUsers = array();
    $bccUsers[] = "your.client.email@mail.com";
    $bccUsers[] = "user.1@mail.com";
    $bccUsers[] = "user.2@mail.com";

    $send = Mail::send('email.test', ['body' => $body],
        function($mail) use ($email, $subject, $bccUsers){
            $mail->from("sender@mail.com", "Email Sender")
                ->to($email)
                ->bcc($bccUsers)
                ->subject($subject);
        });
```